# Error:Cannot call method 'reverse' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, reverse

I have in console(Ctrl+J) chorme as error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'reverse' of null

In following code:

```
///normal number formatting/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////    
$(document).delegate('input.numeric:text', 'keyup', function () {
    $val = $(this).val().match(/[0-9]/g).reverse().join("").match(/[0-9]{1,3}/g).join(",").match(/./g).reverse().join("");
    $(this).val($val)
});
```

How fix this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error says that this part returns `null`:

```
$(this).val().match(/[0-9]/g)
```

The value contains no numbers. I suggest you validate:

```
$(document).delegate('input.numeric:text', 'keyup', function () {
    $val = $(this).val().match(/[0-9]/g);

    if ($val) {
      $(this).val($val.reverse().join("")
                      .match(/[0-9]{1,3}/g).join(",")
                      .match(/./g).reverse().join(""));
    }
});
```